# Get all keys from nested map

Tags: dictionary, nested, key, elixir

- I did this task using [`iteraptor`](https://hexdocs.pm/iteraptor) libary, how can i do it using only elixir fuctionc not external libraries for example using [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2)

```elixir
defmodule MapanalizTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest Mapanaliz

  test "all_path_list(prev_result, xmap, prev_path)" do
    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{}, []) == []
    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{a1: 1}, []) == [[:a1]]
    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{a1: 1, a2: 1}, []) == [[:a1], [:a2]]
    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{a1: %{b1: 1}}, []) == [[:a1], [:a1, :b1]]
    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{a1: 1, a2: %{b1: 1}}) == [[:a1], [:a2], [:a2, :b1]]

    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{a1: 1, a2: %{a2b1: 1, a2b2: 1}}) ==
             [[:a1], [:a2], [:a2, :a2b1], [:a2, :a2b2]]

    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{a: %{c: 1, d: 1}, b: %{e: 1}}) ==
             [[:a], [:b], [:a, :c], [:a, :d], [:b, :e]]

    assert Mapanaliz.all_path_list(%{z1: %{y11: 1, y12: 1}, z2: %{y21: %{x221: 1}}}) ==
             [[:z1], [:z2], [:z1, :y11], [:z1, :y12], [:z2, :y21], [:z2, :y21, :x221]]
  end
end
```

- SOLUTION I did it like that using `Iteraptor` module, but how can i do that using only buildin functions

```elixir
defmodule Mapanaliz do
  def all_path_list(xmap) do
    case xmap do
      %{} -> []
    end

    xmap
    |> Iteraptor.reduce([], fn {k, _}, acc ->
      [Enum.join(k, ", ") | acc]
    end, yield: :all)
    |> :lists.reverse()
end
```

Comment: As an author of `iteraptor` library, I can ensure you, it’s all written in [tag:elixir] and is OSS, so you might go check its code to see how to achieve that without external libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a built-in function, this is typically a case for [recursion](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html) since you want to iterate on a tree:

```elixir
defmodule Mapanaliz do
  def all_path_list(map, path \\ []) do
    Enum.flat_map(map, fn {key, value} ->
      new_path = path ++ [key]
      children = if is_map(value), do: all_path_list(value, new_path), else: []
      [new_path | children]
    end)
  end
end
```

Explanation:

- we "loop" on the map keys and values
- if the value is not a map, we just add the current path
- if the value is a map, we get all its children paths by making a recursive call to `all_path_list`

There are probably many ways to implement this using recursion.
Here I went with [`Enum.flat_map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#flat_map/2) because we want to merge all paths in a single list, not a list of lists.
But you can probably make it more efficient by passing a list accumulator and reversing the list at the end.